# What applications does linear programming have in data science?

Tags: optimization, career, linear-programming

I'm currently learning about linear programming in my degree. I'm wondering how this is relevant to anything in data science?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have an optimization problem the first question that you have to ask yourself is.

Can I make it a Linear Programming problem?

For python I normally use Gurobi. Here is a basic example to get started: https://www.gurobi.com/resources/food-manufacture-i/

You can also do Machine Learning with it, that is the hot topic nowadays, but if you can make it a linear programming problem you will achieve optimality.